# SAPUI5 Error_Log in Frontend: Statuscode 202: User does not have the sufficient authorizations

Tags: authorization, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-gateway

I made a SAPUI5 app. When I call it with my developer authorization, everything runs fine. When my customer runs it with his limited authorizations, he gets the message "User does not have the sufficient authorizations". This happens to him only with my app. Others run fine - so there must be a mistake in my settings.

I find this message in transaction `/IWFND/ERROR_LOG`:

> T100 Error Info: /IWBEP/CM_MGW_RT000;
>
> ICF Node: odata;
>
> HTTP Status Code: 202;
>
> Backend Error: yes;
>
> Error Text: User does not have the sufficient authorizations;

I created in Frontend in transaction `PFCG` a role, which contains the *SAP Fiori Tile Group*, the *service* (which is active), and the *SAP Fiori Tile Catalog*. I noticed, that in the role menu, my service is not a child of the Tile Catalog (which is in a corresponding role that works) and I don't know how to fix this or if that is even a mistake.

I also added the authorization for RFC object `/IWBEP/FGR_MGW_CLIENT_IF`. I copied this from another service, which is running for my client. So I came up to try and error. But by now, I have no further ideas.

Has anyone an idea that could help me find the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the user's ID in Tcode - su53, log in again with the app and check if the user is getting Authorization failure for his Id.

It should show that a certain value/service is missing.
Like this -

[image]

Then you check in Tcode- PFCG, Display Authorization Data if that particular Role has that Service or not.

In my case, it was that my team had added the Service for Obj IWSG and forgot to add it to IWSV. So I got the failure for my user as in the attached image.